# Polymer iron-ajax test if file exists

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a polymer element, which starts with an iron-ajax call to a file, which works fine. But when I change the page, it tries to do an iron-ajax again in that same element but with different parameters, which do not exist. Everything works but I get a GET error in the console. How can I check if a file exists before iron-ajax gets it?

Comment: You shouldn't be asking yourself how to check whether a page exists or not, but rather prevent requesting invalid URLs. If you control the backend, then you surely _must_ know which URLs are valid and which are not.

Comment: This is true and I know I can do that, but i's a bit of a hassle in this setup. It loads any one of 4 elements, based on some parameters. Each element than loads (correctly) the files it needs to load. However, when I click on a link to go to another element, the first element tries to fire the iron-ajax with the parameters of the second before moving to the second element and then loading correctly there. So on the outside all looks fine until you look at the console.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the `auto` attribute from the `iron-ajax` and trigger the request manually after you know it is safe to do so?

Comment: Thanks! That's a much more elegant solution and it works great. Thanks for helping me learn.

Comment: I found another solution also. Add something like `last-error='{{notFound}}'` to the `iron-ajax` call and that gives an object if the file is not found so you can use that to either notify the user with a 404-message or do some other action.